# CDN (custom logging parameter)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, infrastructure

I'm looking for CDN which be able to set custom logging parameter.

This mean some parameters are ignored, but the parameters are logged.

```
<Client request>
http://example.com/response&some_param=logging

<CDN response (no origin request)>
http://example.com/response

<CDN logging>
time / date / ip / url / some_param=logging
```

I think Cloudfront is not possible this and another CDN too.

Please tell me which CDN to achieve this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By parameters, I assume you mean Query Strings (QS). A correct QS would look like this (incl. a question mark):

```
http://domain.com/foo/bar?parameter=value&anotherparameter=anothervalue
```

What you're asking for, is a CDN solution that let's you ignore QS for the cache (meaning that QS will be stripped away before caching) but at the same time, QS should be logged. 
Check out [this solution](https://www.keycdn.com/support/cdn-log-format/) how you can forward CDN logs to your server including QS (while [ignoring QS](https://www.keycdn.com/support/pull-zone-settings/) for the cache).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about two different things.

1. Cache setting: usually the URL is the cache key, with the option to include query string as part of the cache key or not (when included, sometimes it is called unique cache).
2. Query string logging: this is straightforward, and CDN should allow you to choose whether to log query string or not.